# Unable to display image in react nextjs while using dangerouslySetInnerHtml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was trying to create a simple WYSIWYG editor in nextjs. Here I came across this problem, where I have to display the uploaded image to the screen. This could be easily done by creating a blob URL of the image and using the URL in the src of the image **IF** you are not using dangerouslySetInnerHtml. But while using it the link appears broken. This was the result I was getting on the console.

```
blob:http://localhost:3000/f28f5781-d2b0-4a20-9d56-10b9ae7f66e7/:1 GET blob:http://localhost:3000/f28f5781-d2b0-4a20-9d56-10b9ae7f66e7/ net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Here is what I tried to do. On image upload event, I trigger a function that sets the image URL using React.useState() , eg setImageUrl(objectUrl) . here's the contentEditable div.
:

```
<div
            style={{ margin: "10px", border: "none", outline: "none" }}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            contentEditable
            data-placeholder="Enter text here"
            onKeyUp={(e) => handleKeyUp(e)}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: innerHtml }}
            onClick={(e) => handleContentEditableChange(e)}
          >
```

here is the innerHtml ,Let me know if more info is needed. thanks

```
setInnerHtml(
        ${innerHtml}
        <p>${tempText}</p>
        <img src=${imageUrl}/>
      );
    /* here is what I am doing with the file, this code is triggered just after I upload the file */

    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    setImageUrl(objectUrl); 
// the imageUrl is same as the one above in image src . P.S. i have made use of readAsDataUrl as well but failed to get the desired result
```

Comment: Could you show the whole implementation of the component? Anyways, you either need `readAsDataURL` or `createObjectURL` and `readAsDataURL` is asynchronous.

Comment: I have updated the code, thanks for pointing that out. But I have clearly made use of createObjectUrl() to get the blob URL.Let me know if you still need to see the code, as it is full of the unnecessary and unused portion that I need to clear before posting it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is reading the img src as `blob:http://localhost:3000/sth/` while it should be `blob:http://localhost:3000/sth`. To fix it, wrap `imageUrl` with quotes or remove the `/` or do both:

`<img src="${imageUrl}" />` or `<img src=${imageUrl} >` or `<img src="${imageUrl}" >`